# file uploading time (document.getElementById("file").files[0].name) getting error

Tags: javascript, php, html

In javascript (document.getElementById("file").files[0].name) is giving  not able to the file name for the  loacl sever

> Error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

HTML

```
<?php $j=10; for($i=0; $i<=$j;$i++){?><div>

    <a href="#" title="Give some input related to this track" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lgdata<?php echo $i;?>"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lgdata<?php echo $i;?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<form  data-parsley-validate class="form-horizontal form-label-left" action="../text.php" method="post">

    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple="multiple" required >

     </p> 
     <span id="uploaded_image"></span>

      <div>

       </div>
 </div>
</div>
<?php }?>
```

javascript

```
 <script>

                $(document).ready(function(){

                 $(document).on('change', '#file', function(){
                  $('div.loader').show();

                  var name = document.getElementById("file").files[0].name;
               });

               });

             </script>
```

Comment: If we temporarily discard the PHP part of your code then there is no problem with it. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mkpxreLz/ . There is no error. Even with the PHP running and generating the HTML, it's hard to see how you could be getting that error.

Comment: However, I see that in the PHP you are creating this same HTML 10 times via a loop. This will give you a different problem because in HTML it is not valid to create the different elements with the same ID. Think about it, if you create `<input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple="multiple" required >` 10 times, then later when you run `document.getElementById("file")` ...which one of the 10 copies is supposed to be selected? JavaScript doesn't know which one you meant. Therefore, it will always choose the first copy, and considers the rest to be invalid,  and pretends they don't exist.

Comment: To get round that, you could give all your inputs a class, and then use the class as the selector when binding the event. Then you can have the same code running for several copies of your input. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mkpxreLz/1/